# puppet git clone private repo as user with vcsrepo module

Tags: git, puppet

I'm using a masterless puppet install to configure my dev box and I need to clone a private repo, but vcsrepo won't run as a specific user so the wrong ssh key is being used.

According to the [vcsrepo docs](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo) this should run as my non-root user:

```
vcsrepo { '/path/to/repo':
  ensure   => present,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  user     => 'blake',
}
```

But every time it runs I think it is still running as root because I get this error:

```
Error: Execution of 'git clone git@github.com:private-org/private-repo.git /home/blake/code/private-repo' returned 128: Cloning into '/home/blake/code/private-repo'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

If I manually execute git clone it works just fine so I know the correct ssh key is setup for my user account.

**update 1:**

Okay I added the `--debug` flag but it doesn't really give any more info.

```
Debug: Executing 'git clone git@github.com:private-org/private-repo.git /home/blake/code/private-repo'
```

But I think it has something to do with my 'known_hosts' file. If the host is known it works just fine, otherwise it shows the error above. So somehow I need to figure out how to populate the 'known_hosts' file so the the vcsrepo command will work.

Comment: Can you update and show what happens if you run puppet with `--debug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Host key verification failed` error in this case has to do with a missing host in the 'known_hosts' file.

If you do a `git clone` from the command line it will prompt you do add the host entry to the 'known_hosts' file, but this won't work if puppet runs the `git clone` command.

To solve the problem I added the output of `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com` to my 'known_hosts' file via puppet using the [file_line](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#file_line) type. I also turned off 'HashKnownHosts' in my `.ssh/config` file.

Comment: stuck exactly at same point, can you show me you puppet code - puppet fails with same error for me

Comment: my puppet code is the same as what I have in the vcsrepo block in the question. Did you run `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com` and verify that it is in your known_hosts files? I currently don't have HashKnownHosts turned off like in my original answer so that might not be needed. Try running `puppet apply --debug` and see if that shows anything helpful.